# Custom Data send from excel file to .csv file in PHP

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I have 600 000 data in one excel file. I want to send first 30 data to a csv file and another 30 data to another csv file and it's continued whenever 600 000 data send to csv file. How can i do it with php code?

Note: after complete this process i want to 20 000 csv file where include 600 000 data serially.

Comment: So, to clarify you want to split a file of 600,000 lines into files with 30 lines each?

Comment: yes, any solution?

Comment: I'll add an answer. What is the extension of the original file?

Comment: Now i have .xlsx file of 600,000 lines. I want 20,000 .csv files with each 30 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `box/spout` library which is built for jobs like this.

```php
$reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createReaderFromFile('/path/to/file.xlsx');

foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
    if ($sheet->getIndex() === 0) {
        foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            // write CSV files
        }
        break; // no need to read more sheets
    }
}


$reader->close();
```